# Can I overload the notation for operators that are assigned to bool and list?

Tags: isabelle

*(NOTE: If I can get rid of the warning I show below, then I say a bunch of extraneous stuff. As part of asking a question, I also do some opinionating. I guess that's sort of asking the question "Why am I wrong here in what I say?")*

It seems that 6 of the symbols used for `bool` operators should have been assigned to syntactic type classes, and `bool` instantiated for those type classes. In particular, these:

```
~, &, |, \<not>, \<and>, \<or>.
```

Because type annotation of terms is a frequent requirement for HOL operators, I don't think it would be a great burden to have to use `bool` annotations for those 6 operators.

I would like to overload those 6 symbols for other logical operators. Not having the usual symbols for an application can result in there being no good solution for notation.

In the following example source, if I can get rid of the warnings, then the problem is solved (unless I would be setting a trap for myself):

```
definition natOP :: "nat => nat => nat" where
  "natOP x y = x"
  
definition natlistOP :: "nat list => nat list => nat list" where
  "natlistOP x y = x"
  
notation
  natOP (infixr "&" 35)    
notation
  natlistOP (infixr "&" 35) 
  
term "True & False"
term "2 & (2::nat)"  
term "[2] & [(2::nat)]" (*
OUTPUT: Ambiguous input produces 3 parse trees: 
  ...
  Fortunately, only one parse tree is well-formed and type-correct,
  but you may still want to disambiguate your grammar or your input.*)
```

Can I get rid of the warnings? It seems that since there's a type correct term, there shouldn't be a problem.

There are actually other symbols I also want, such as `!`, used for `list`:

```
term "[1,2,3] ! 1"
```

Here's the application for which I want the symbols:

- [Verilog HDL Operators](https://www.utdallas.edu/%7Eakshay.sridharan/index_files/Page5212.htm).

## Update

Based on Brian Huffman's answer, I unnotate `&`, and switch `&` to a syntactic type class. It'll work out, or it won't, indeed, binary logic, so diversely applicable. My general rule is "don't mess with default Isabelle/HOL".

```
(*|Unnotate; switch to a type class; see someday why this is a bad idea.|*) 

no_notation conj (infixr "&" 35)

class conj = 
  fixes syntactic_type_classes_are_awesome :: "'a => 'a => 'a" (infixr "&" 35)
  
instantiation bool :: conj
begin
definition syntactic_type_classes_are_awesome_bool :: "bool => bool => bool" 
  where "p & q == conj p q"
instance ..
end

term "True & False" 
value "True & False"
declare[[show_sorts]]
term "p & q" (* "(p::'a::conj) & (q::'a::conj)" :: "'a::conj" *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "undeclare" special syntax using the `no_notation` command, e.g.

```
no_notation conj (infixr "\<and>" 35)
```

This infix operator is then available to be used with your own functions:

```
notation myconj (infixr "\<and>" 35)
```

From here on, `\<and>` refers to the constant `myconj` instead of the HOL library's standard conjunction operator for type `bool`. You should have no warnings about ambiguous syntax. The original HOL boolean operator is still accessible by name (`conj`), or you can give it a different syntax if you want with another `notation` command.

For the `no_notation` command to work, the pattern and fixities must be *exactly* the same as they were declared originally. See `src/HOL/HOL.thy` for the declarations of the operators you are interested in.

I should warn about a potential pitfall: Subsequent theory merges can bring the original syntax back into scope, causing ambiguous syntax again. For example, say your theory `A.thy` imports `Main` and redeclares the `\<and>` syntax. Then your theory `B.thy` imports both `A` and another library theory, say `Complex_Main`. Then in theory `B`, `\<and>` will be ambiguous. To prevent this, make sure to put all your external theory imports in the one theory file where you change the syntax; then have all of your other theories import this one.

Comment: Brian, there's a potentially decent solution after all. I was expecting the worse, like, "Live with it." Thanks for the general answer, and the heads up about keeping other theories from changing things back. I'd upvote it, but I'm a one-pointer right now, so I can't.